# Variable padding that changes along with AppBar size

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar, singlechildscrollview

I created a frosted AppBar has a SafeArea wrapping. I want a scrollview that scrolls under it, but i'm unable to code a variable padding that adds the SafeArea of the AppBar to the top padding of the SingleChildScrollView. Does anyone have any tips? My appbar is at `appbar:`. The code for the body Scaffold follows bellow:

```
home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFF6FFF1),
          extendBody: true,
          extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
          // Body
         body: SingleChildScrollView(
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(top: 90, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 8),
                child: Text(
                  lorem(paragraphs: 4, words: 480),
                ), 
              ),

appBar: FrostedAppBar(
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.help_outline_rounded,
                  color: lightColorScheme.tertiary,
                  shadows: const [
                    Shadow(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        blurRadius: 2,
                        offset: Offset(1, 2))
                  ],
                ),
                onPressed: null,
                iconSize: 40,
              )
            ],
            title: Text(
              'Title',
              style: GoogleFonts.racingSansOne(
                  fontSize: 40, color: lightColorScheme.primary),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.menu_rounded,
                color: lightColorScheme.tertiary,
                shadows: const [
                  Shadow(
                      color: Colors.black, blurRadius: 2, offset: Offset(1, 2))
                ],
              ),
              iconSize: 40,
              onPressed: null,
            ),
          ),
```

[Example of why I need variable padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcQ1o.jpg)

[Scaffold body content going under the appbar and being blurred by it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nqDs.jpg)

Thank you very much for your time!!!

Comment: I thought about using Size.copy but didn't know how to implement it. It's the first app i'm developing.

Comment: wrap your scaffold with safeArea not the appBar.

Comment: use kToolbarHeight

Comment: Can you give us a little bit more code? Where is your AppBar? Why are you using Stack? Why do you even need SafeArea? Can you explain in more details how exactly you want your UI to look? Thanks!

Comment: @Lasslos05, updated the post.
Removed the stack, it was a leftover from when the appbar was in the scaffold, had forgot about it. Added images of the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Scaffold` with `SafeArea` widget.

```dart
SafeArea(
   child: Scaffold(
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by wrapping the Text (SingleChildScrollView child) in a SafeArea.

```
body: 
            top: true,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 10, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 8),
              child: SafeArea(
            Text(
                lorem(paragraphs: 4, words: 480),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```